# How to find list of columns from the given 10 table names?

Tags: sql

We need to provide list of columns for around 50 tables/views names (which will be given in one excel). I am using below query for which I need to replace table name and run the query for **50 times**. Is there a one shot query whose where clause will have all the table names? e.g.

```
Select table_name,column 
from  
where table_name in(Mytableq,Mytable,2...Mytable50)
```

Query I am using currently:

1.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbCFRMart.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'vwPDPSubCase'
```

2.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbCFRMart.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'vwDDPcase'
.
.
.
```

50.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbCFRMart.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'vwXYZcase'
```

Comment: `... where TABLE_NAME in (N'vwPDPSubCase', N'vwDDPcase', ... , N'vwXYZcase')`

Comment: do u have similar suffix or prefix to all tables ? `ex: vw`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.